# QGIS Singleband pseudocolor Continuous symbology

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, color-ramp

If you want to configure the symbology of a raster in QGIS using render type 'Singleband pseudocolor', you can choose out of 3 modes to generate values in the table (continuous, equal interval and quantile). Although, I do not find information on the logic behind these modes. More precisely I'd like to know how the 'Continuous' mode classifies the values. In fact, my gut feeling expects this to be the same as 'Equal Interval' but obviously it isn't...
Could someone please point me to some documentation or explain what this 'continuous' mode does exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, but my guess is that Continuous refers *exactly* to the colour ramp (that you get by clicking on the cooler ramp itself). If it has 30 defined colours, then you get 30 different values in your symbology.

With Equal interval, you define the number of values, and QGIS interpolates the values of the colour ramp.

And finally, Quantile gives you the values that separate your data into classes that have the same number of points. You can clearly see what's happening when the interpolation is set to Discrete.